# Magento 2 | Which refrenceContainer to use for adding additional button on 'Create New Order Page?

Tags: magento2, containers, reference

[image]

I am adding a new button with Add Products button at:

Sales->Order->Create New Order->New Add Product Button as shown in screenshot!

I searched for the relevant referenceContainer in vendor but all in vain. Is this approach right or have to do it by some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vendor, button html renders in `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items` class from `getButtonsHtml()` method.

You can write after plugin method and add your custom button in your custom plugin.

Also you can try to write after plugin for method `addButton()` of `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items` class.

**Note :** "Add Products" button comes from js `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js`

Following code will help you to create plugin.

Create di.xml file in `etc\adminhtml` folder and add follwing code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items">
        <plugin name="vendor-module-order-create-items-block" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Create\Items" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

After di.xml you need to create your plugin file Items.php at location `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Create` as below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Create;

class Items
{
    public function afterGetButtonsHtml(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items $subject, $result)
    {
        $url = 'http://www.google.com';
        $result .= $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class
            )->setData(
                ['label'=>'Add New Products', 'type'=>'button', 'id'=> 'add_new_products', 'class' => 'action-secondary action-add', 'on_click'=>"window.location.href='" . $url . "'"]
            )->toHtml();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example for it? what I understand is it will done by plugin. Can you explain more.

Comment: Yes you understood correct, you need to write plugin `afterGetButtonsHtml()` of class `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items`

Comment: Kindly write plugin for me in answer, i am doing this for the first time.

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @RanjitShinde it worked! Can you please also guide in this next step ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249716/magento-2-how-to-extend-algolia-search-for-adding-products-in-order-at-admin-s